# Dynamically add a SAML2 authentication provider using Sustainsys.Saml2 in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I'm trying to dynamically add a SAML2 authentication scheme using `IAuthenticationSchemeProvider` in ASP.NET Core and the Sustainsys.Saml2 library:

```
schemeProvider.AddScheme(new AuthenticationScheme("myAuthScheme", "myAuthScheme", typeof(Saml2Handler)));
```

Along with the scheme, I need to configure the `Saml2Options` that go along with it. I'm attempting to do this using `IOptionsMonitorCache<Saml2Options>` like so:

```
samlOptionsCache.TryAdd("myAuthScheme", options);
```

When I then attempt to authenticate using this scheme, I get the following error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object. Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.Saml2Urls..ctor(HttpRequestData
>   request, IOptions options)
>   Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.SignInCommand.Run(EntityId idpEntityId, string
>   returnPath, HttpRequestData request, IOptions options,
>   IDictionary relayData)
>   Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Handler.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties
>   properties)

So it looks like the properties are never being linked with the scheme.

I'm not sure that I'm going down the correct path with this. Is it possible to dynamically register a scheme in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out it was the just the logger that wasn't instantiated, all the other options were fine. I solved this by adding...

```
options.SPOptions.Logger = new AspNetCoreLoggerAdapter(loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Saml2Handler>());
```

...when I set up the options.

`loggerFactory` refers to an injected instance of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory`.

Comment: Nice catch. The reason this doesn't work automatically is that the Saml2 `IPostConfigureOptions<Saml2Options>` is not wired up when you call `AddScheme` yourself instead of relying on the supplied `AddSaml2` method.